# How to make synchronous redis get/set in node

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

I'm trying to test a connection to redis. I'm successfully setting a key/value pair with a TTL of 10 seconds. I just need to capture the response synchronously and return the value.

I've tried using promises, async/await etc

```
let setRedis = function(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(redisClient.setex('foo', 10, 'bar'))
    })
}

// execute test and record result
testRedis = function() {
  setRedis().then(function(res){
    console.log('done setting')
  })
  console.log('exiting function')
}
```

I need "done setting" to occur before "exiting function"

Comment: Your last line is confusing. You achieve the goal of printing `done setting` before `exiting function` by using async/await, but that won't cause `testRedis` to return the result of `setRedis()`.

Comment: You also need to include which redis library you're using for us to be able to meaningfully answer you.

Comment: There is no reason to want to do this, but it can be done using a module such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-rpc

Comment: Instead you should just return a Promise from your function, and anything that relies on knowing the result from `testRedis` can await (or call then on) that Promise.

Comment: Where is `redisClient.setex()` documented?